# Increase apache requests per second

Tags: performance, apache, benchmarking, apachebench

I want to increase apache's request per second figure.
I'm using apache benchmark to get it and it's not going over 500.

```
ab -n 100 -c 100 http://localhost/
```

this is the command I'm using it gives me 500 RPS

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.212 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      17925 bytes
HTML transferred:       900 bytes
Requests per second:    472.05 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       211.843 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.118 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          82.63 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        9    9   0.2      9       9
Processing:    20  150  36.8    160     200
Waiting:       19  148  36.6    159     200
Total:         30  159  36.8    169     209

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
 50%    169
 66%    176
 75%    182
 80%    187
 90%    200
 95%    206
 98%    209
 99%    209
 100%    209 (longest request)
```

this is the whole coutput.
I'm using worker mpm for this with configs as--

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
  ServerLimit          200
  StartServers         200
  MaxClients           5000
  MinSpareThreads      1500
  MaxSpareThreads      2000 
  ThreadsPerChild      64
  MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

I suppose these are pretty high figures never the less I keep increasing it and nothing seems to change.
The application itself doesn't contain anything it only prints 'Hello World' with cherrypy.
I want to increase it to like 2000RPS my Ram is 5GB(using a VM).

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you've set in your configuration look wrong - but the only way to get the right numbers is by [measuring how your system behaves](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/accurate-capacity-planning-with-apache.html) with real traffic.

Measuring response time across the loopback interface is not very meaningful. Measuring response time for a single URL is not very meaningful. Measuring response time with a load generator running on the same machine as the webserver is not very meaningful.

Making your site go faster / increasing the capacity is very difficult and needs much more testing, data and analysis [than is appropriate for this forum](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning).